# How to Create Base fragment which hold multiple Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am Working on one application and in this application I want to use `ViewPager` But the problem is that I have only one `Activity` and I want to create base `Fragment`. in this Fragment I want to define `ViewPager` because it will be common for all `Fragments`. I have tried a lot but not able to get it. So can any one help me please.

Comment: The viewpager should be defined in the Activity, not the fragment itself.
What exactly is your problem? You can create your BaseFragment and created subclasses, and set your FragmentPagerAdapter to hold your fragments

Comment: Actually problem is that if i define view pager in activity so it will be common for all fragment of application because i have only one activity that is common for all.And i want view pager only for fragments so i thought i will define view pager in base fragment so it is work for those fragment which i will define in fragment class.

Comment: (1) Create `ViewPager` inside `FragmentActivity` (2) create child fragment for pages of viewpager \n **Update** : If you want to have view pager only for fragment then create FragmentActivity for them and when your task with viewpager is complete, call other Activity for rest of cases

Comment: Can you explain it more

Comment: @Kushal can we use both Activity and fragmentActivity in one Application.

Comment: @user4736426: yes we can

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to add a fragment inside an ordinary fragment. But for this purpose you can us the Fragment inside the appcompat-v7.
This means you also have to use the appcompat-v7 FragmentManager.